# How do I show a list of applications in Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, menu, unity-dash

I'm more of a visual person.  I prefer scanning a list of icons to being presented with a search box and being forced to remember the *name* of the thing I want.

Is there any way to view a list of installed apps similar to the "Applications" menu in previous versions?

Comment: isn't there a quicklist on the elauncher that says more applications and displays all of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you open *Dash->More Apps* or the *Application Lens*, the applications are shown as icons with their name underneath. Both these options also allow filtering the results by a category.

[image: app lens]

Comment: Oh, wow.  I've earned my "Duh" badge for the day.

Answer (score 5):

There is a MUCH better way than the answer provided here:

Open the terminal and type the following:

```
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

That will give you exactly what you're looking for.