# How to find available applications on Unity

Tags: unity, applications-lens

On previous versions of Ubuntu I had a menu listing installed applications, sorted by categories.

I never could find anything similar in Unity. The dash never lists any application so I must find the application's executable file in the console and manually make a shortcut.

I never was able to display anything [looking like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42833/how-do-i-show-a-list-of-applications-in-unity).

Is there something I missed ? Do I have to install a lens or something ? How do you access the famous "application-lens" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press Super(windows key) + A to open the Application's Lens or click on 1. as shown here:

[image]

You will see three lists / categories:

- Recently used
- All installed
- Available for download

Click on the second one (2.) and you will see a list with all your installed applications.

Filter them by clicking on Filter results (3.).

Comment: Thanks. Using `super+A` works. I don't know why but clicking on "1" doesn't work for me (I tried it before).

Answer (score 2):

If you want something similar to the Applications menu from GNOME, you can type the following in a terminal:

sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator

It took me a while to find that, and I think it's better than the Unity Dash.

Hope that helps you!!!